# Elasticsearch 6.2.4: how to order aggregation results by _score?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got the wanted query results in query part ordered by _score desc. Now I need to extract 3 fields of each document. I want to achieve like:

```
select distinct field1, field2, field3 from table A;
```

I just tried:

1) Use collapse to remove the repeated values

```
GET index/_search
{
  "collapse" : {
        "field" : "filed1.keyword" 
    }
  ...
}
```

But the problem is that it would only keep the distinct values of filed1 but ignore the values of field2 and fiel3. For example,  we have 2 records like:

```
[1, "a", "b"], [1, "c", "d"]
```

Using this method we can only get one record since they have the same value of field1. I want the distinct combined values of these three fields. We can use inner_hits to get the distict value of the second field, but according to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-collapse.html: Second level of collapsing doesn’t allow inner_hits. That means it cannot be applied to get dicstinct values amoung multiple fields (>2).

2) Use aggregations:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "field1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "field2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": field2.keyword",
            "missing": ""
          },
          "aggs": {
            "field3": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "field3.keyword",
                "missing": ""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

It returns the distict values of [field1, field2, field3] but the order of the documents is changed. They're ordered by **doc_count** but not _score and we cannot get the information of _score in the results.

So how can we get the distinct combined values without changing the current order (since we have customed the documents order in "query" part)? Or how can we  order aggregation results by _score?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample query as how you use `aggregations` for `_score`.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "<yourfield>": "<yourquery>"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "myaggs": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "_score"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And hence your above aggregation query would be in the below form:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "query":{  
      "match":{  
         "field1": "search non-search"
      }
   },
   "aggs":{  
      "myaggs":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"field1.keyword",
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "myotheraggs":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"field2.keyword",
                  "order": {
                    "_term": "asc"
                  }
               },
               "aggs":{  
                  "myotheraggs2":{  
                     "terms":{  
                       "field":"field3.keyword",
                       "order": {
                          "_term": "asc"
                       }
                     },
                     "aggs":{  
                        "myscoreaggs":{  
                           "terms":{  
                              "script":"_score",
                              "order": {
                                  "_term": "desc"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }

   }
}
```

So basically, the above query would return you in the order of `field1 field2 field3 score` where `field1 field2 field3` would be sorted based on the `asc lexicographical` order while _score would be sorted in `desc` order

For e.g. below is the sample sorted data as how it would appear

```
field1|field2|field3|score
--------------------------------
non-search|lucene|graphdb|1
search|lucene|elasticsearch|2
search|lucene|elasticsearch|1
search|lucene|solr|2
search|lucene|solr|1
```

### Updated Answer Post Chat

```
POST someindex/_search
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "myagg":{  
         "terms":{  
            "script":{  
               "source":"doc['field1'].value + params.param + doc['field2'].value + params.param + doc['field3'].value",
               "lang":"painless",
               "params":{  
                  "param":", "
               }
            },
            "order":{  
               "_term":"asc"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Kamal for the answer. While the problem is, order by _score should be the priority because the most relevant results should be on the top. Inspired by this answer, I tried to put the "myscoreaggs" as the parent aggregation so that it aggregates by _score as the priority. But the problem is, I get repeated values of ` [field1, field2, fiel3]` in different buckets and strangely they have different _score. Can you please help?

Comment: @Elva Score is calculated by `match` part at the top in above query. And yes there would be duplicates if you order by/aggregate score because there could be two documents with say `nike` but in one of them it appears many times and in other it appears only once. Generally search applications have query results in actual search results while your facets/refinements would be aggregation results. Aggregation has nothing to do with relevancy. Its a different concept. I'd suggest you revisit your design. Glad to help if you have any further queries.

Comment: Score is calculated for `each` document and `each` document may have different score. So when you create aggregation by score, you'd eventually end up with duplicate `field1 field2 field3` but with different `score`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of document score-- do you mean other fields in the index will affect the score of the document? In the query I just use match/query_string/term to do search among only three fields: `field1, field2 and field3 `  bacause I only concern about the search results of the 3 fields. In this case, will the times that one keyword appears in other fields (except the 3 fields) affect the final score of a document?

Comment: @Elva could you check the answer now. I've updated in section *Updated Answer Post Chat*

Comment: I've checked the new DSL but unfortunately, I found the order of the records is not what I want. I just want the the order consistent with the that of the query results. That means, if I only use the query part, I would get the most relevant documents and I need to keep this order and don't want to change it. Now I need to exact 3 fields (distinct) from these documents, that's the point.